# MPI and cluster

Tags: c++, cluster-computing, mpi, hpc

Just learn to program on a supercomputer consists of ~100 nodes, each node consists of 4 Xeon CPUs and 64GB ram.

What I want to do is assigning jobs to each node and then creating local multi-threading programs on each node, what I want to know is,by default, when MPI create a group of processes, is there a 1-1 mapping between each task process and one particular local node or not?(in my case, it is a node consist of 4 Xeon CPUs with totally 24 cores and 64GB ram).

Comment: Are you asking if a process will float between nodes?

Comment: Yes, I just hope a particular MPI process can stick to one particular node during the entire lifespan of the process, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: I am not aware of any widely used MPI implementation that is able to migrate live processes across nodes. Process migration goes against MPI-3.0 specification that allows for the creation of subcommunicators that encompass ranks which could attach to a shared memory block (i.e. they run on the same shared-memory system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPI will run M processes on N nodes where M may be less than, equal to, or greater than N.

[This site](http://www.clustermonkey.net/MPI/processes-processors-and-mpi-oh-my.html) describes the setup.

I can't find a direct answer to your question, but there are a number of sites on the internet discussing `process migration` and `checkpointing`. But the general theme of these sites seems to be that this is still very much a work in progress. As such, I wouldn't expect that this would be happening automagically in your MPI implementation.

[This site](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node143.htm#Node147) discusses the `MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME` command, which can be used in process migration, but states that "nothing in MPI requires or defines process migration; this definition of MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME simply allows such an implementation". With this command, you can at least check if your code is being actively migrated.

Comment: Many thanks, so I guess MPI works kind like how OS handle threads, it can assign process to any particular nodes at runtime for whatever reason it see fits. But one last thing, I think the minimum computing unit that a MPI process can occupy is a node, which means, there wont be two MPI processes occupy a single phyiscal node (althrough one node may contain many CPUs) at any given time, am I right?

Comment: From the first site I link to, I would interpret it that more than one process may be running on a single physical node. All the supercomputers I've worked with have had job submission scripts which take a "processes per node" parameter as input. The alternative would be that there is one process per node, but multiple threads; however, I don't think it works in this latter way.